# What is the origin of "see things in a different light" or "see things in a new light"?

Tags: etymology, idioms

I was really wondering if this phrase is modern (post-electricity) or older than that. 
(musing) I was driving home one day last week and the sun was hitting a building I had not previously noticed in a spectacular way. The idiom came to my mind and got me thinking: if this was coined really long ago, then asking someone to "See things in a different light" would have implied "let some time pass" as well (with sun moving etc).

Comment: Hi Mircea, welcome to English Language & Usage. If you think you might use our site again (and I hope you do!), please make sure you take the [Tour].  :-)

Comment: In addition to what @user070221 already quoted from etymonline. "spiritual illumination ... The figurative spiritual sense was in Old English; the sense of "mental illumination" is first recorded mid-15c."

Comment: Before electricity, candles and oil lamps (each one emits a different type of light, I believe) were used in order to "see" where one was going. The concept of using "light" to mean "clarity" and "understanding" I think is pretty universal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figurative usage of "light" in that respect dates well before electricity. Light, on the other hand, has always existed. Early usage instances appear to draw on the religious metaphor of [Light](https://www.gotquestions.org/God-is-light.html):

> Meaning "a consideration which puts something in a certain view" (as in in light of) is from 1680s.

(Etymonline)

Early  usage instances:

[Religious Library](https://books.google.it/books?id=H0eXM-6wzlwC&q=in%20a%20new%20light&dq=in%20a%20new%20light&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi63erYztDcAhXEJJoKHcGbC2QQ6AEIUDAG), Volume 1 American Tract Society, 1671

> - A new light, in which things appear far otherwise than they did before.

[The Trials of Sir. Geroge Wakeman](https://books.google.it/books?id=pXQ0AQAAMAAJ&pg=RA1-PA128&dq=%22in%20a%20different%20light%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjo9trgz9DcAhUkLZoKHeWDBoIQ6AEIRTAE#v=onepage&q=%22in%20a%20different%20light%22&f=false) 1709:

> - For the consideration is not, how it now appears to you or to me, who look upon it in a different Light, and on contrary Principles from theirs

Answer (score 4):

Interesting question! I did a Google Ngram search and found a reference to

[Papers of the Governors: 1681-1747 - Page 619](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22different%20light%22&lr=lang_en&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1590,cd_max:1744,lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&ei=wBNkW8n2OamTlwTul6b4CA&start=10&sa=N&biw=1366&bih=662&dpr=1)

> Pennsylvania. Governor, ‎George Edward Reed - 1681 - ‎Snippet view - ‎More editions
>
> Your extraordinary manner of stating the Case would indeed **set everything in a different Light**; but while you can call your sending up about three hundred armed Men with Drum and Trumpet to terrify our Inhabitants by the name of levying of ...

Comment: I can see a reference on Google ngram dating back to 1587, but I don't understand how you traced your reference.

Comment: @Strawberry I only searched for the words "different light". The earliest reference in print (from my limited search) seems to be the one I gave.

Comment: Yes, but how do you find it from the ngram?

Comment: @Strawberry once you've searched, there are some links at the bottom of the ngram. I clicked there and found the reference: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=different+light&year_start=1500&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdifferent%20light%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Oh - it's obvious now you say it!! :-$